# Laravel Query Buider Group By Not Getting All The Records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by

I am trying to get the data using `groupBy` on `type` field from my `transaction` table. I am using this query

```
DB::table($this->table)
    ->select()
    ->whereRaw($where['rawQuery'], isset($where['bindParams']) ? $where['bindParams'] : array())
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->get();
```

But it is not giving the `complete records`. There are more than 10 records in my table. But it is giving me only two. One for type=1 and another for type=2. It is selecting only on record from each type. I am expecting that i will get all the `transactions` based on `condition` grouped in `two result set`. Anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: What you expect from `->groupBy('type')` ?

Comment: i am expecting that i will get all the transactions based on condition grouped in two resultset

Comment: isn't two resultsets two different selects?

Comment: `based on condition grouped in two resultse` what condition ? and grouped means rows here. so you are getting right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to call `Collection` groupBy instead. Just put groupBy after get(). It should work.

```
DB::table($this->table)
    ->select()
    ->whereRaw($where['rawQuery'], isset($where['bindParams']) ? $where['bindParams'] : array())
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('type');
```

Comment: I'm glad to know it helped you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Faq::where('type','host')->get()->groupBy('category');

Comment: Add more to your answer than just code, because this does not explain how does it solve the problem by OP.

Comment: funnyly this is the answer what im lookin for :D